# Inserting datetime into a SQLite Database

Tags: sqlite, datetime, python-3.x

I am trying to insert the time into my database but when I print what I inserted it isn't correct. I printed the time variable before inserting it into the database and it is "12:01:09.149059". It was working fine when I was using **strftime** but I switched because the time was off.

```
from datetime import datetime
time = str(datetime.now().time())
cur.execute("insert into apple values (?,?,?)",(price,time,date))
con.commit()

#prints:
>>>('132.75', "<method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>", 'Apr 27, 2015')
```

Comment: the output does not correspond to the code. In your actual code, you are missing `()` after `.time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert a Python method object into a string, which is defaulting to its representation, which you don't want.  Try this instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p")
cur.execute("insert into apple values (?,?,?)",(price,time,date))
con.commit()

#prints:
>>>('132.75', "Apr 27, 2015 09:38AM", 'Apr 27, 2015')
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `datetime` object manually; `sqlite3` provides default adapters.

Answer (score 5):

`sqlite3` module already provides adapters for `datetime.datetime` objects. You could pass `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date` objects as is:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> db.execute('select ?', (datetime.now(timezone.utc),)).fetchone()
('2015-04-27 20:22:26.951841+00:00',)
```

You could [define your own adapters if necessary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#registering-an-adapter-callable) e.g., to pass `datetime.time` objects:

```
>>> from datetime import time as datetime_time
>>> def adapt_time(t):
...     return str(t)
... 
>>> sqlite3.register_adapter(datetime_time, adapt_time)
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> db.execute('select ?', (datetime.now(timezone.utc).time(),)).fetchone()
('20:24:00.867221',)
```

Store date and time together (just pass `datetime` object without *any* conversions). Use UTC time or aware datetime objects.

Comment: You DO NOT want to insert datetime aware objects. They will be stored as plain strings and some weeks later you will end up scratching your head about why the comparisons in your queries do not work correctly (lexicographic ordering is broken when you compare across timezones). The only safe way is to convert to UTC and store in a one of the variants at https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values (and always the same one!). This conversion can be achieved at insertion time using the SQLite built-in function `datetime`.

Comment: @MartinCejp: it depends on your use case. If you want the comparison to work and if you don't need to store the original utc offset in your case, then it might be simpler to store "seconds since epoch" instead (`aware_dt.timestamp()`).

Comment: Sure, and it will also take up a bit less space on disk (if stored in a column with numeric affinity). However, you lose the convenience of being able to skim the data visually.