# SQLite Python: Inserting a default value (timestamp)

Tags: python, sqlite

perhaps a silly question. I nabbed this SQL function from another website:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS score (
                X1 string,
                Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                )""")
```

My understanding of this SQLite function is that it would default to the current timestamp on the system clock if a value isn't specified. I am just not sure how to "insert" this default value as part of an execute function:

```
    c.execute("INSERT INTO score VALUES (?, ?)", (String, **(WHAT GOES HERE??)** ))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You wouldn't do that. If you want to use the default value, don't specify the column in the insert statement.

Comment: Read this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900785/inserting-datetime-into-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in SQL Lite called date, you can use it to compute the current date:

`SELECT date('now');`

or get the current unix timestamp.

`SELECT strftime('%s','now');`

see this reference for more usages: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS score (
                X1 TEXT,
                timestamp_record timestamp
                )''')

c.execute('''INSERT INTO score VALUES (?, datetime('now','localtime'))''', (some_variable_string,))
conn.commit()
```

This is how I got it to work. I replaced one of the '?' with the timestamp function (datetime) and only included the text variable along with a ',' at the end. This seemed to work for me as I was having the same problem.

There may be some code best practice that say don't put the function directly into the database but I could not figure how to use SQL Lite's timestamp function as described in the link below.

[Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)